# How do I read from a real floppy disk to a virtualbox OS?

Tags: virtualbox, floppy

I am currently running ubuntu 14.04 with virtualbox 5.0. I got my hands on some floppy disks and a drive, and wanted to read what was on them. Unfortunately, ubuntu cannot read whatever the format flopies are, so I decided to use Virtualbox with windows 95. I now have a new problem:

how can I set up my usb floppy drive to use in my windows 95 virtualbox machine?

Answer (score 3):

Following from [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-usb.html):

Go to your Virtualbox Settings. In the <kbd>USB</kbd> section, check the two tick boxes to ensure your USB device can be shared.

Install the VirtualBox Guest Additions package for your system.

If your device is "greyed out" in the USB filter <kbd>Devices</kbd> > <kbd>USB Devices</kbd>, then you need to fix group permissions.

In a terminal, run

```
usermod -a -G vboxusers yourUserName
```

to ensure you are in the vboxusers group.

You should now be able to forward your USB device to your virtual OS.

Comment: I might need more than that. my old dell latitude floppy reader (some reason they put a mini B port on it) does not show up after using this command.

Comment: Did you make sure to install the Guest Additions? Do other USB devices show in this list? You will also have to log out and log back in to make sure the group changes took effect. ALSO, try `sudo apt-get-install dkms open-vm-dkms`

Comment: Old drive died. Trying again with same type.